# Is it impossible to impregnate a woman during her period, and in the few days after?

Tags: obstetrics

I've heard that the chances of impregnating a women during her period, or in the few days (up to a week) after her period, are close to 0 percent.

Does this mean that I don't need to use a condom during this interval of time between her period and up to a week after?

Comment: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe the opposite is true: That she's actually more likely to fall pregnant closer to and during her period than farther away from it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is basic information on how the menstrual cycle & ovulation occur. http://womhealth.org.au/conditions-and-treatments/understanding-your-menstrual-cycle-fact-sheet

With that said, I charted my cycles for years & was well aware of how my body worked overall.  I have actually taken education on the use of charting to avoid pregnancy.  It worked very well for me for a decade & then one time I ovulated on day 4 (which for most women would be during menstruation) and that is how I got pregnant with one of my children.

So there is no time in a cycle you can have unprotected sex and be absolutely certain you will not ovulate, even if you have always ovulated on a predictable schedule.  I did know this.  It was okay with me overall to have that unplanned pregnancy, hence why I was comfortable taking that risk as a married person who had children already.  If you do not want a child, wear a condom, every time.  It really *is* what you need to do.  You cannot know for sure what a body will ever do because it is impacted by stress, sleep, foods, etc and hormones - things you cannot always account for. Even when a woman takes hormonal birth control, there is a failure rate.  None of the birth control options other than sterilization have close to a 0% chance & anyone telling you that is not being factual.

Comment: Plus one for a well-written, down-to-earth, spot-on answer. :O) ... Another very helpful resource:  [What are Fertility Awareness Methods?](https://www.plannedparenthood.org/learn/birth-control/fertility-awareness). Quote from that site: "Fertility awareness methods (FAMs) are ways to track your ovulation so you can prevent pregnancy. FAMs are also called 'natural family planning' and 'the rhythm method.'"